# How rails console provide result set on querying if Lazy Loading is enabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lazy-loading

I have a database table `users`. I am trying to query the database to fetch all users whose ages are greater than 18.

```
adult_users = User.where('age > 18')
```

The above query will not be executed, as per lazy loading feature, instead it will just create a Active Record Relation. The actual query will be executed only when you call `adult_users.first` or if you do some other operations with it.
But in rails console, even if you hit `User.where('age > 18')`, you can see the query executing.
How could this happen?

Comment: "how could we get the result set without executing actual query?" This doesn't make any sense. You can't get a result set without executing the query. Where would the results come from? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: What I meant is, lazy loading does not execute the query. For example, adult_users = User.where('age > 18'), will not execute query, instead it will just create a Active Record Relation, and the actual query will be executed only when you call adult_users.first or if you do some other operations with it. But in rails console, even if you hit User.where('age > 18'), you can see the results. How could this happen? Does this make sense now?

Comment: See Vasfed's answer below. On a terminology note, in Rails "lazy loading" (versus "eager") refers to whether or not a query on one model will load all of the associated records for a relation. The terms are unrelated to the issue you're talking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In console it does execute the query while inspecting the `ActiveRecord::Relation`

If logging is enabled you can even see the `User Load` entry.

If you type

```
adult_users = User.where('age > 18'); nil
```

then variable will not get inspected and no query run